Search for all directories that are smaller than 4MB
I want to display all directories that are smaller than 4MB using find command.
Already tried find / type d -size -4000000c(same with a dot instead of/`) but both combinations display files too. What kind of switch should I put here to search only for directories? Maybe there is another command for this purpose?
how it looks

do you really want directory size and not total size of the files and subdirectories inside each directory? Consider mkdir /tmp/t; dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/t/big bs=10M count=1; du -sh /tmp/t; find /tmp/t -type d -size -10000c

Suggesting du command.
To list content of all directories in Mb units:
du -m / 2>/dev/null

-m produce directory size in Mb.
/  start inspecting from root directory (hope you know what you are doing)
2>/dev/null ignore all errors related to directories access
Once you have all the directories you can filter them with pipe to awk script
du -m / 2>/dev/null | awk '$1 < 4 {print $2}'

$1 < 4 filter only lines where 1st field less than 4
{print $2} from filtered line print 2nd field

Really use the command:
find / -type d -size -4000000c

Don't forget minus (-) for each -type and -size options.
Without minus for -type option, find command searches in /, type and d directories.

After some further research, I modified the du combination to:
du -m * | awk '$1 < 4'

and that makes do!
